# Djano many to many relation with User

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-related-manager

```
class Relationship(models.Model):
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='from_user')
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='to_user')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=RELATIONSHIP_STATUSES)

field = models.ManyToManyField('User', through=Relationship, symmetrical=False, related_name='related_to')
field.contribute_to_class(User, 'relationships')
```

This is working fine follow and unfollow

```
users = User.objects.all()
{%for u in users %}
    {% if not request.user in u.related_to.all %}
          <input type="submit" value="Follow"/>
    {% else %}
          <input type="submit" value="UnFollow"/>
    {% endif %}
{%endfor%}
```

But I want to get the Relationship status field using the User object to find out the status of all user is Following or mutual with authenticated user.
I do not want to create loop. Like above in follow and unfollow I have check request.user inside or not, like that I want to check whether status is mutual or following

```
users = User.objects.all()

{% for u in users %}
   // here I want to get the Relationship status field using the User object to find out the status of all user is Following or mutual with authenticated user
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: I think this may help you,

```
{% for u in users %}
    {% for relation in u.relationship_set.all %}
        from: {{ relation.from_user.username }}
        to: {{ relation.to_user.username }}
        status: {{ relation.get_status_display }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

try also 'from_user' or 'to_user' instead of 'relationship_set'

Comment: It is named `related_to`.

Comment: related_to is used for manytomany relation, i think here we can use either relationship_set or  from_user or to_user in this code  {% for relation in u.relationship_set.all %}

Comment: Thanks. i do not want to create loop. Like above in follow and  unfollow I have check request.user inside or not, like that I want to check whether status is mutual or following

Answer (score 0):

Inside Views.py

```
users = User.objects.all()
mutual = []
for me in members:
    try:
       Relationship.object.get(to_users=me, from_users=request.user,status='Mutual')
       mutual.append(True)
    except Relationship.DoesNotExist:
       mutual.append(False)
```

Inside template

```
{% if mutual == True %}
Mutual
{% endif %}
```

Any better idea please suggest because above code run query for each user. To many queries